# mongod - is it possible to remove log like "NETWORK ... received client metadata from ..."?

Tags: mongodb, logging

I'm using `mongo` with the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) - and I'm currently on **v4.0.13**.

My container's logs were really heavy with a lot of useless lines, this is why I decided to add the `--quiet` [option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-quiet).

However I still have a large amount of useless logs as following:

```
...
2020-04-14T13:06:00.565+0000 I NETWORK  [conn205] received client metadata from 172.16.1.3:56396 conn205: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.10.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "x86_64", version: "4.15.0-76-generic" }, platform: "CPython 3.6.9.final.0" }
...
```

These lines are not really relevant to me, and I wonder to remove them to reduce the "noise" but I don't understand how.

My current log verbosity:

```
> db.getLogComponents();
{
    "verbosity" : 0,
    "accessControl" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "command" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "control" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "executor" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "geo" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "index" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "network" : {
        "verbosity" : -1,
        "asio" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "bridge" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "connectionPool" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        }
    },
    "query" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "replication" : {
        "verbosity" : -1,
        "heartbeats" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "rollback" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        }
    },
    "sharding" : {
        "verbosity" : -1,
        "shardingCatalogRefresh" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        }
    },
    "storage" : {
        "verbosity" : -1,
        "recovery" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        },
        "journal" : {
            "verbosity" : -1
        }
    },
    "write" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "ftdc" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "tracking" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    },
    "transaction" : {
        "verbosity" : -1
    }
}
```

If you have a clue just let me know!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think the built-in logger allows completely turning off those messages.  You might be able to have the mongod send log messages to syslog, which can then filter logs however you like and output them to a file anywhere on the system.

Comment: @Joe thank you for the anwser... too bad :( I really hoped a better workaround with a mongo configuration